# How to process requests asynchronously in Java server with I/O multiplexing?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Suppose I am writing a Java server, which communicates with clients over TCP/IP.

The server uses `I/O multiplexing`. There is a single thread `T0`, which waits on `selector` and handles client connections. For instance, if a connection is ready for read then `T0` reads the data from the connection.

Suppose the server has read an incoming request and now it is ready to process it. Since the processing takes time the request is processed in another thread `T1` and `T0` returns to wait on the selector.

Suppose that `T1` has finished the processing and created a response. Now `T0` should start writing the response to the client connection. So my question is: how does `T1` send the response to `T0` ?

Comment: All communication with the client will be via a Socket and on the 2nd thread T1. T0 will be used only to wait for new connections.

Comment: So you have a thread per client connection. Can you serve 1000 clients ?

Comment: Yes, one thread (at least) per client connection. Regarding your second question, I don't do this type of programming, so I can't answer this specific question about 1000 clients, but I suppose so, although I also suppose that there must be a limit on computer hardware and software resources regardless of any programming language. Of course, you'd let any thread end (naturally) if the socket closes.

Comment: Ok. So you probably cannot serve 1000 clients using a (native) thread per connection. However you _can_ do it with I/O multiplexing. That's why I/O multiplexing is useful.

Comment: I'm going to have to bow out on this as I am less than a complete novice to the concept of multiplexing. I will watch and hopefully learn from this question thread.

Comment: Can you use libraries/frameworks, or are you writting code by hand?

Comment: Thread T1 should read, process and return the response after getting work to be done from the selector. No need to pass anything to T0.

Comment: @afsantos Yes, I can use any library/framework. I do not think it matters though.

Comment: As far as i got to know nio, t1 should enqueue its result to some write queue for the chanel that the request came from and signal writable, no? I had a good tutorial on that. I'll post it when I find it again.

Comment: @Michael I was going to write an answer, but I think this fits better as a comment. If you're willing to experiment with some framework, I recommend [Netty](http://netty.io/index.html). It abstracts away the messy details of Java NIO, and allows a fair degree of fine tuning (number of threads, for instance). They have some tutorials there to get you started.

Comment: @afsantos Thank you. Do you know how `Netty` works under the hood ?

Comment: @Michael Last time i worked with it I had to dig into the source myself, and I can recall some of its details. Netty has a group of threads (`EventLoopGroup`, may be only one thread) and each of these threads loops on a selector (`EventLoop`). Each new connection (`Channel`) is bound to a thread, and whenever an event occurs, Netty calls the appropriate handler. You define the handlers for the events you're interested in (read, exceptions, etc). Event handling is done by the I/O threads, but you may also call `write` from an *outsider* thread. Netty ensures that it will be written safely.

Comment: @Michael Summing up, you may start Netty with 4 threads and still be able to serve 1000 clients with those threads only, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

The same thread T1 should read, process and return the result to the client.

Here is an outline on how to do it with java nio api without linking the number of threads to the number of clients.

```
**//Thread T0** //wait for selection keys
...
Iterator it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator( );

while (it.hasNext( )) { 
    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) it.next();
    // Is a new connection coming in? 
    if (key.isAcceptable( )) {
        ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel channel = server.accept()
        // Set the new channel nonblocking
        channel.configureBlocking (false);
        // Register it with the selector
        channel.register (selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    // Is there data to read on this channel?
    if (key.isReadable( )) {
       processRequest (key);
    }

    it.remove( );
}

...

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
...
void processRequest(final SelectionKey key) {

    **//Thread T1-T50** //deal with request
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {            
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        //read data from channel, process it and write back to the channel.
    });
)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the same "thread per connection" solution suggested and discussed earlier.

Comment: The T1-T50 threads work only when the client sent anything. They are not busy waiting for something on the socket.

Comment: @Michael This solution doesn't use a thread per connection, since the executor's threads can (and will) be reused for all active connections. There will always be *x* threads, independently of the *y* connections active at the moment. In particular, *x* can be 1 (`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`) and you have exactly the `T0` and `T1` you describe in your question.

Comment: @dcernahoschi Thank you. Got it :) Suppose a slow client sends a 10K message a byte per minute. Do you suggest submit a new task for every byte to read. Looks like too much overhead.

Comment: @afsantos Thank you for the correction. I will think of it.

Comment: @Michael Buffer until getting to some threshold bytes and than process. Every time the buffer is not full release the thread. I don't know exactly your application that's all I can say.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a server thread that does nothing but blocking on `ServerSocket.accept()` and as soon as it accepts a connection, submits it to an `ExecutorService`.  While in theory, you can have any number of threads, I would not do it since it makes your application vulnerable to DoS attacks.  Instead, limit the maximum size of your thread pool and have it degrade gracefully if the server load goes over the top.

There is actually [a small example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) of how to do this in the documentation for the `ExecutorService`.

**Update:** I might have misunderstood your question.  As I understand now, you are aware of the solution suggested above but want to use [*synchronous multiplexing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing) on purpose.

It would help to understand what kind of service your server provides and what is likely the limiting factor (CPU, disk I/O, networking, …).

You could assign a unique request ID to every incoming connection and insert a handler object into a map under that ID.  Then, if a connection becomes ready, the network thread picks the respective handler and asks it to accept a certain amount of input / produce a certain amount of output.  Whether this is applicable to your situation will of course depend on the service your server offers.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I think that this solution is suboptimal. The problem is that you have a thread per client connection and then you cannot server 1000 clients, for instance, while I/O multiplexing (on thread in a selector loop) can serve more.

Comment: You can make a thread pool with 1000 workers if so you desire.

Comment: I mean that 1000 threads is too much for a single box. Anyway using a thread per client connection is not efficient in comparison with one thread in a tight selector loop.

Comment: I agree that synchronous multiplexing will probably be more efficient.  And in C, that would be the straight-forward way to go.  On the other hand, I don't think you'll kill any modern machine with 1000 threads.  (More likely with 1000 sockets…)  `ExcutorService`s feel more natural in Java to me.

Comment: @Michael equally you can have a thread pool of 1 for 1000 clients.  The size of the thread pool is not determined by the number of clients, in fact you can have more threads than clients if they have particularly demanding clients.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you. Unfortunately, it seems suboptimal to allocate a thread to handle a client connection. What if a client is very slow ? Using a "thread per connection model" I allocate the whole thread just to read a byte per minute. Looks a bit silly, does not it ?

Comment: @Michael it is sub-optimal to have a large number of threads and having 10K threads can waste a whole CPU. While it is more complicated to use less threads, there is nothing stopping you from doing either way AFAICS.